# Python multiprocessing a class method

Tags: python, multiprocessing

It's my first time using multiprocessing, but I'm stuck with a problem that I kind of know the reason, but I have no idea how to fix it. So here's the deal, I have a Stream class:

## Stream.py

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import multiprocessing as mp

from LEDController.BaseClass import BaseClass
from LEDController.Device import Device


class Stream(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, device: Device):
        super().__init__(__name__)
        self.__p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = None
        self.read_process = mp.Process(target=self.read, args=[])

        # Stream Settings
        self.defaultFrames = 1024 * 8
        self.format = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.channels = device.channels
        self.rate = int(device.defaultSampleRate)
        self.input = True
        self.frames_per_buffer = self.defaultFrames
        self.input_device_index = device.index
        self.as_loopback = True

        self.__open()
        self.stop()

    def __open(self):
        try:
            self.logger.info('Trying to Open Stream')

            # Open Stream
            self.stream = self.__p.open(
                format=self.format,
                channels=self.channels,
                rate=self.rate,
                input=self.input,
                frames_per_buffer=self.defaultFrames,
                input_device_index=self.input_device_index,
                as_loopback=self.as_loopback,
                # wasapi_fill_silence=True
            )

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(e)
        else:
            self.logger.info('Stream Opened')

    def start(self):
        self.stream.start_stream()
        self.read_process.start() # ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        self.logger.info("Stream Started")
        return True

    def stop(self):
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.logger.info("Stream Stopped")
        return True

    def is_stopped(self):
        return self.stream.is_stopped()

    def read(self):
        try:
            while not self.is_stopped():
                # Process Data
                data = self.stream.read(self.defaultFrames, exception_on_overflow=False)
                data_int = struct.unpack(str(2 * self.defaultFrames) + 'h', data)

                print(data_int)
                # return data, data_int

        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(e)
```

That Stream Class is responsible for reading the output device data in real-time, process this data, and send it to an Arduino (i haven't implemented the Arduino, that's why it's not in the code yet). But when I try to start the Process it throws this error.

## Error

```
File "E:\PycharmProjects\LedProject\LEDController\Stream\Stream.py", line 52, in start
    self.read_process.start()
  File "E:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "E:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "E:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "E:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "E:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

It seems to be something to do with Pickle, but I have no idea what to do. Any idea on how it can be fixed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Arguments aren't pickled, objects are, and there is nothing special about the object being referred to by `self`... How are you trying to leverage multiprocessing to begin with? This looks IO bound so you could just use threading

Comment: So threading is a better option?

Comment: Maybe, I dont really understand what you code is doing, there's not much context. Again, what **exactly** are you trying to accomplish? You mentioned an error in the comments, **post the full error message including the stack trace.** You should be providing a [mcve], please read [ask] and the [help]

Comment: I  rewrote part of the question, sorry about the order one. Hope that's better now